# Observer redirected too many times

Tags: magento2, event-observer, redirect-url

I have set a pre-dispatch observer like this:

**\etc\frontend\events.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
  <event name="controller_action_predispatch">
      <observer name="Custome_controller_action_predispatch" instance="Namespace\Module\Observer\PreDispatch" shared="false" />
  </event>
</config>
```

**\Observer\PreDispatch.php**

```
public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    { 
      if($this->isLogin()){
        $customerId = $this->customerSession->getCustomer()->getId();
        $customer = $this->_customerRepositoryInterface->getById($customerId);
        $addresses = $customer->getAddresses();
        if(empty($addresses)){
          $url = $this->helper->getBaseUrl() . 'custom/action/';
          $this->_responseFactory->create()->setRedirect($url)->sendResponse();
          exit;
        }
      }
    }
```

the problem is i always got an error like this:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Because your code is incorrect. You're using a very generic event. Essentially you're code has a infinite loop, because you're using `controller_action_predispatch` it will always go back to the observer.

The name is clear `predispatch`, so before redirecting or before "routing".

Answer (score 0):

Your code will redirect customer before visiting each page, So your code will have an infinite loop.

To resolve this issue you can add condition to check current url before redirecting, something like below code

```
$currentControllerAction = //get your current Url here;

$url = $this->helper->getBaseUrl() . 'custom/action/';
if(empty($addresses) && $currentControllerAction != $url){
    $this->_responseFactory->create()->setRedirect($url)->sendResponse();
    exit;
}
```